# Selecting and clicking an HTML option via automation using ie.DOM in VB

Tags: dom, internet-explorer, automation

I'm unable to select an option and click it programmatically vai ie.DOM.  Here's what the HTML looks like with the options and the onchange javascript call:
[image: code behind dropbox]

And here's what the dropdown looks like:
[image: Select Report]

Here's what I tried that doesn't seem to have any effect on the page

```
Set ddl = ie.Document.getElementById("ddlReports")
    For Each itm In ddl.getelementsbytagname("option")
        If itm.Value = "12" Then itm.SELECTED = True: Exit For
    Next itm
    itm.Click
```

I've also tried this but it just clears the page and returns a 0.

```
ie.Navigate "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlReports\',\'\')', 0)"
```

It's supposed to reveal a button that allows me to retrieve the report.

Comment: Is there any error showing when it doesn't work in IE? I can't reproduce the issue using the code you provide, it can select the dropdown list correctly. Could you please provide the url of the website you automate so that we can have a test? Or you can provide a minimal code snippet which can **reproduce the issue**.

Comment: You're correct, it does select the item in the dropdown.  I thought it wasn't because the itm.Click doesn't work.  When you manually select it, the page then shows a button to extract the report.  I cannot get that button to show either by itm.Click or with the Navigate Javascript line.  Unfortunately, credentials are needed to see the page.  Would you know something other than itm.Click that I could try?

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to do a Submit for the form instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to submit the form after selecting an option in the dropdown. Here's the code that worked.

```
Set ddl = ie.Document.getElementById("ddlReports")
For Each itm In ddl.getelementsbytagname("option")
    If itm.Value = "12" Then itm.SELECTED = True: Exit For
Next itm
ie.Document.getElementById("frmAshleyExtracts").Submit
```